# How do you manage your Amazon RDS connection string?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

How do you manage your Amazon RDS connection string when you need to failover or upgrade your server?

Do you need to go into every server and change the config file to point to the new server in the connection string?

Is there any equivalent of an *Elastic IP Address* service for Amazon RDS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RDS connection string is a CNAME record with a 60 second time to live.
During RDS failover the CNAME is updated to point to the old standby ec2 instance.
As long as clients connect to the RDS connection string they will automatically pick up the new RDS server following a failover.